# flask process multiple request, with different variable

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, concurrency, multiprocessing

```
app = Flask(__name__)

message = 'hello'

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return message

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is my flask app, running with gunicorn on google cloud,

Short-question-and-problem:

what i expect
when user1 make request to our website our message1 will show on web, and
when user2 make request to our website our message2 will show on web,
how can I acheive this,

Explaination:
actually  in real message1 is instance which take arguments, like
in project folder we have five files namely user1, user2,user3,user4,user5, then actual message will instance("user1","user1") where instance first parameter check if file exist and second in name of file,
but i want to acheive that when we receive first request from internet, our instance load with file1, and when concurrently user2 make request to our web our web will load with user2 file,

i have file and all logic for rest of my app work except, when request 1 arrive, load instance with file1, and when concurrently user2 arrive load instance with file2 and handle request,

if dont have time to answer please mention only name of the tool or technology,
i am actually new in web development, and in flask.

Comment: In your case, you need to use websocket. [Websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is not Flask; it's a protocol.